# Folder to Binary

Tags: file, binary

I was wondering if someone could help. I've used a small CMD Bat that allowed me to dump the files of a Binary into human readable files so I can edit them, my problem is that I can't return it into a Binary.

The files were dumped as a folder, I was wondering if there was any way to reconvert it into a Binary.

The file is from a game, I'm simply trying to translate it into my mother tongue.

Comment: Every file is binary. If you open it with a program, they know how to interpret this file. For example a simple textfile contains the binary representation of the characters often as ascii-code.
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange

How did you "convert" the file to human readable and what format are they now?

Comment: I see, then I guess what I'm trying to say is that I converted it from Hex to ASCII and would like to convert it back. Sorry, I'm not very code literate. 

I converted it through a file someone else made, basically it's a small Bat that you drag and drop in CMD, place a command next to it and drop the file you want converted afterwards.

This produced multiple xml files and a couple of .txt files, which are what I'm trying to compress back into a single Hex Binary file again.

Comment: Please what you are executing

Comment: I'm trying to translate a game from CH to my common tongue, the language pack files are inside an xml, which when uncompressed, has more xmls and a single bin file in it. 

I've gone and dumped the bin file into human readable language and replaced the chinese text with the language I want the game to be in, now I need a way to return that file into a bin. If that makes sense.

Comment: So you decompiled the game's exe, changed some text and want to compile it again?

Comment: Yes, something like that. It's an mmo, so it isn't exactly the .exe.

Comment: I forgot about this post, but want to add something like a conclusion.

Comment: Most file extension do imply the inner structure or at least the type of content, like XML-JPEG-DOC-PDF.

Binary (bin) files do not define an inner structure. You can extract text from this file by applying the ascii table to everything and take the readable parts. But putting the translated text back into that bin needs a deep knowledge about this structure.

For example, parts of the data can point to other parts of the file. If you add data in between, you need to update that pointer. You cannot find those easily.